# Winnovative HTML to PDF converter for Angular generated page

Tags: c#, html, angular, pdf, winnovative

I'm trying to use Winnovative Html to PDF converter in my .NET MVC hosted Angular (4.1.3) application.

When I use it for non-Angular pages (e.g. http://google.com), it works fine. However, when I tried to convert an Angular page, the PDF just shows

```
Loading...
```

(this is from app-root tag in my index.cshtml file).

My C# code is as follows:

```
public byte[] GeneratePdfFromPage()
{
    var converter = new PdfConverter();
    converter.LicenseKey = "My License Key";
    var urlOfAngularPage = "Angular page url";
    return converter.GetPdfBytesFromUrl(urlOfAngularPage); // this returns just "Loading..."
}
```

Does anyone know how to convert an Angular page with Winnovative Html to PDF converter?

I tried to set 10 (seconds) to `ConversionDelay` property but no luck.

Comment: Any luck with this? Try this ... 

public ActionResult GeneratePdfFromPage()
{
    var converter = new PdfConverter();
    converter.LicenseKey = "My License Key";
    var urlOfAngularPage = "Angular page url";
   var fcr = new FileContentResult(converter.ConvertUrl(urlOfAngularPage), "application/pdf");
                fcr.FileDownloadName = fileName;
                return fcr;
}

Comment: Thanks Drytin, I tried it but no luck. (Same result)